# How to port DeltaSpike @WindowScoped beans to JSF 2.2+?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, jsf-2.3

I am porting some applications from DeltaSpike to JEE 8. I am using Apache MyFaces as JSF 2.3 implementation, and Primefaces 8.0 on top of it.

There are some beans annotated with [´@WindowScoped´](http://deltaspike.apache.org/javadoc/1.8.2/org/apache/deltaspike/core/api/scope/WindowScoped.html) in the legacy code. How to do this with JSF 2.3?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

just use DeltaSpike, there is no "JSF native" alternative yet. It will likely be available in Faces 4.0: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/faces-api/issues/1509

Comment: Thanks! I'll follow your advice for these projects.